# Dynamically set the number of textview in a given space

Tags: android, textview

In my app I want to show tags to the users. As of now am showing only 5 tags.
[image]
[image]

P.S. Ignore the color part.

As of now am using 5 different `TextView` with `wrap content` to show the text.

But as you can see, in the latter case, there are lot's of empty space in the top row.

Is there any way by which I can dynamically select the number of tags to be fetched from server which will fit in the given space?

Like in the 2nd case, I can show 3 tags in the first row and 3 in the second row. I'll like to fix a `Tab space` between two tags and based on available spcae, the number of tags should be displayed.

Comment: You can try this too.  [TagView](https://github.com/Cutta/TagView)

Answer (score 0):

Given the layout you posted you could use a TableLayout setting `android:stretchColumns="*"`, this will stretch all columns and make it "tabular"

Answer (score 0):

Try using [FlowLayout](https://github.com/blazsolar/FlowLayout). It works the same way as you want.

Comment: Can I edit the layout of the tags ? Is it customizable? I don't want the box and I'll like to add the heart image and a score of the tag.